# Newbie Mistakes: Python Text File Reading

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

**Edit**

I wrote this post when I first starting coding. My program was a "login system" and I use the term very loosely. I did not really use it much but it was a little passion program whilst I was at school. A lot has changed since then. Anyway I'll leave you to read the awful code and post. I hope it helps.

---

**Original Post**

I wrote this code to read information in from a text file, that stores all these details and it works.

```
loginsystem=open("loginsystem.txt","r")
myuser=loginsystem.readline()
mypass=loginsystem.readline()
print(myuser)
print(mypass)
```

But the text document it reads from leaves a extra line at the end of the string that is read in. Here is the desired output of the program:

```
myuser
mypass
user1
pass1
user2
pass2
user3
pass3
user4
pass4
user5
pass5
```

Comment: I'm not sure understand your problem. What do you mean `it works but the text document it reads from doesn't let it get the information right it leaves a extra line`?

Comment: Could you post some example for the text file you're reading from, and the ouput of your program based on the file example?

Comment: Here is the link to a picture of the file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/176171143/Python.png

Comment: Any blank line at the end of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that your output appears like

```
myuser

mypass

...
```

instead of

```
myuser
mypass
```

You want to strip the newline characters from your `readline()`s:

```
myuser = loginsystem.readline().rstrip()
```

However, it is probably better practice to use `with` so your file handling is properly taken care of.

```
with open("loginsystem.txt", "r") as loginsystem:
     ...
```

Additionally, if you want to read all pairs of usernames and passwords, you can do something like:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
with open("loginsystem.txt", "r") as loginsystem:
    for line1, line2 in izip_longest(*[loginsystem]*2):
        username = line1.rstrip()
        password = line2.rstrip()
        print username, password
```